# Custom Xcode Picker with Identity Inspector

Tags: xcode, ios7, uipicker

I am trying to make a custom Xcode UIPicker with only numbers 1-10. Is there any simple way to do this with an Identity Inspector or if not, what is the best way to go about making this simple UIPicker?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't create a picker using only Inerface Builder. There is no equivalent to `UITableView` Static cells for `UIPicker`. You need a view controller but it's not that complicated. The view controller need to implement the `UIPickerViewDataSource`, `UIPickerViewDelegate` delegates. Here is the basics for a single column picker with the values 1 to 10.

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController () <UIPickerViewDataSource, UIPickerViewDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *pickerView;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    
    self.pickerView.delegate   = self;
    self.pickerView.dataSource = self;
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

#pragma mark - UIPickerView Data Source & Delegate

- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView
{
    return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 10;
}

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", row + 1 ];
}

- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    // TODO do something with the selection
}

@end
```

To create a minimal iOS app with a picker. Create a new Project select single window application. Replace the code in ViewController.m with above. Edit the story board and add a picker. **Important** You need to connect the picker view in the storyboard to the `IBOutlet` in the code.

**Not Connected**
[image: IBOutlet not Connected]

To connect the outlet you should be editing the storyboard in assistant editor mode. The assisted editor will display the code and the IBOutlet property. Now "Control Click the picker view in the storyboard and drag to the line of code declaring the IBOutlet. The connection is made when the circle is black in the gutter on the line declaring the IBOutlet property.

**Connected**
[image: IBOutlet Connected]

**Xcode Editing Storyboard in Assistant Editor Mode**
[image: Xcode Editing Storyboard in Assistant Editor Mode]

FYI: By far the best and fastest moving way to learn iOS is the Stanford iTunes U Course:

Developing iOS 7 Apps for iPhone and iPad
https://itunes.apple.com/us/course/developing-ios-7-apps-for/id733644550

You will need to watch a few of the demos to grok how to make connections Interface Builder (IB). The first thing you need to understand is the IB does not create resource or configuration files. The storyboard files contain serialized interface objects. Almost identical to the objects you can create in code.

## Changing the size of the picker text

You need to replace the implementation of `pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:` with your own `pickerView:rowHeightForComponent:` and `pickerView:viewForRow:forComponent:reusingView:`

```
- (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component
{
    return 60;  // Row height in points, Note this should match the height of the UILabel Rect.
}

// FYI points are not pixels on non retina screens 1 point = 1 pixel but on retina screens 1 point = 2 pixels

- (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view
{
    if (view) {
        UILabel *reuseLabel = (UILabel *)view;
        reuseLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", row + 1 ];
        return reuseLabel;
    }
    
    UILabel *newLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 60)];
    newLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", row + 1 ];
    newLabel.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:42];
    newLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
    
    return newLabel;
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for your quick response. I am new to Xcode so how and where would I implement and add the above code? and then once I do, how do I link my picker to the code itself? Thanks again @GayleDDS

Comment: Hi @user3743364 see my updated answer for complete how to steps. Cheers.

Comment: Your help was much appreciated but if I wanted to increase the size of the text how would I go about doing so?

Comment: You will need to implement - (UIView *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView viewForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component reusingView:(UIView *)view and possibly also - (CGFloat)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView rowHeightForComponent:(NSInteger)component instead of pickerView:titleForRow:forComponent:

Comment: Hi @user3743364 see updated answer. I added a section on how to change the text size.

Comment: You are amazing! Thank you for the in-depth tutorial and explanation. Everything makes sense and works perfectly!

Comment: I am sure this should probably go in a separate question but you have been a tremendous help so far. If I wanted to get rid of the box that surrounds the number, how would I go about doing so? Thank you again for the in-depth explanations of the above questions!

Comment: I don't think you can. You could need to create a custom control.